# Prove a sequence Cauchy in a given metric

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ denote the set of all continuous real functions on [0,1] and define the real map $d_1$ on $X x X$ by

$$ d_1(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t) - g(t)| dt   $$

Also, consider the sequence $(f_m)$ of continuous functions on [0,1] with

$
f_m(t)=
\begin{cases}
 0,  \text{if}\ 0 < t \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{m} \\
 m(t + \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{2}), \text{if}\  \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{m} <t\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
1, \text{if}\  \frac{1}{2}  <t\leq 1
\end{cases}
$

Verify that $(f_m)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_1)$

The solution given to me is as follows:

Let $m,n \in N$ with  $m > n \geq 2$. Observe that $d_1(f_m,f_n) = |\frac{1}{2m} - \frac{1}{2n}|$. Since the sequence $ (m^{-1}) $ is Cauchy, $(f_m)$ is Cauchy in $d_1$

Here, I don't get how $d_1(f_m,f_n) = |\frac{1}{2m} - \frac{1}{2n}|$. Can someone explain this part to me?
Thank you!

Comment: I think that you confused $x$ and $t$ several times in your definition of $f_m$. You just need to compute this. Note that you can split up the integral among the several subintervals where you know the definition of $f_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$d_1(f_m,f_n) = \int_0^1 \underbrace{|f_m(t) - f_n(t)|}_{F(t)}\, dt$$
As $m > n$, we can split the integral as
$$\int_0^1 F(t)\, dt = \underbrace{\int_0^{1/2 - 1/n} F(t)\, dt}_{=0} + \int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2 - 1/m} F(t)\, dt  + \int_{1/2-1/m}^{1/2} F(t)\, dt  + \underbrace{\int_{1/2}^{1} F(t)\, dt}_{=0}$$
where the first and last integrals vanish as $f_m = f_n$ on the respective intervals of integration. Thus,
$$\begin{align*}
d_1(f_m,f_n) &= \int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2 - 1/m} |f_m(t) - f_n(t)|\, dt  + \int_{1/2-1/m}^{1/2} |f_m(t) - f_n(t)|\, dt\\ &= \int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2 - 1/m}\left|n\left(t + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \right|\, dt + \int_{1/2-1/m}^{1/2} \left|m\left(t + \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{2}\right) - n\left(t + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2}\right) \right|\, dt 
\end{align*}$$
Can you finish up the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that can help you: Consider $f_3$ and $f_7$. Then
$$
f_3(t)=
\begin{cases}
 0,  \text{if}\ 0 < t \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} \\
 3(t + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2}), \text{if}\, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}  <x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
1, \text{if}\  \frac{1}{2}  <x\leq 1
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
 0,  \text{if}\ 0 < t \leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{6}} \\
 (3t - \frac{1}{2}), \text{if}\, \color{red}{\frac{1}{6}} <x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
1, \text{if}\  \frac{1}{2}  <x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
likewise,
$$
f_7(t)=
\begin{cases}
 0,  \text{if}\ 0 < t \leq \color{red}{\frac{5}{14}} \\
 (7t - \frac{5}{2}), \text{if}\  \color{red}{\frac{5}{14}} <x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
1, \text{if}\  \frac{1}{2}  <x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
So,
$$
|f_7(t)-f_3(t)|=
\begin{cases}
 0,  \text{if}\ 0 < t \leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}\\
\left|0-(3t-\frac{1}{2})\right|, \text{ if } \frac{1}{6} < x \leq \frac{5}{14}\\
\left|(7t-\frac{5}{2})-(3t-\frac{1}{2})\right|, \text{ if } \frac{5}{14} < x \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
0, \text{if}\  \frac{1}{2}  <x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Now compute the integral. Same idea can be used for a general $m$ and $n$.